# Unable to reparse json to xml using js2xmlparser, mapping of fix protocol xml to angular template

Tags: angular, treeview, fix-protocol, xml-to-json, js2xml

I parsed Xml to js(using xml2js library) and mapped it in ng template using ngFor, but on updates and later conversion of js to xml string I used js2xmlparser, but the error goes

setup.component.ts:415 Error: in XML document > element "datadictionaryxml" > element "fix": element name "$" should not contain characters not allowed in XML names

i want a json from xml which can be remapped to xml from the same json, and the structure of xml should not change.